# How can I *SELECTIVELY* modify a multi-dimensional array that's generated with random numbers?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

a) define a 12x12 matrix using (pseudo) random numbers
b) output this matrix
c) alter **only the diagonal** of this matrix (e.g. add a given number to [R0][C0], add a given number to [R1][C1], add a given number to [R2][C2]

I'm able to accomplish 'a' and 'b' without any problem.  I'm able to accomplish 'c' to a limited degree (the results are not what I would expect).

Here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int N = 12;
const int P = 12;

int Matrix_M[N][P] = {0};
int rowSum[N] = {0};
int colSum[P] = {0};

void generateArray();
void addError();

int main()
{
    generateArray();
    addError();

    return 0;
}

void RainGen()
{

    // sets the seed for the number generator
    unsigned setSeed = 1023;
    srand(setSeed);

    // generates the matrix using pseudo-random numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < P; j++)
        {
            Matrix_M[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            // outputs the raw matrix
            cout << left << setw(4) << Matrix_M[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

void addError()
{

    // sets the seed for the number generator
    unsigned setSeed = 1023;
    srand(setSeed);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < P; j++)
        {

            // adds 100 to the previously-generated number in the original matrix
            if (i == j)
            {
                Matrix_M[i][j] = rand() % 100 + 100;
            }

            // outputs the 'adjusted' matrix
            cout << left << setw(4) << Matrix_M[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}
```

Currently, this code compiles but does not give the expected result.  For example, I'm seeing the following in the original matrix:

```
79  59  41  39  ...
24  84  95  0   ...
92  96  37  13  ...
90  58  65  13  ...
.   .   .   .
.   .   .   .
.   .   .   .
```

And, in the adjusted matrix, I'm seeing:

```
179  59   41   39   ...
24   159  95   0    ...
92   96   141  13   ...
90   58   65   139  ...
.    .    .    .    
.    .    .    .
.    .    .    .
```

[0][0] of this matrix is correct.  The other elements of the DIAGONAL in the 'adjusted' matrix are not correct.  For example, in [1][1], we see 159.  I would expect to see 184 in [1][1].  But, the code is taking the element in the first row of each column, adding 100 to it, then placing that value in the desired position in the diagonal (e.g. in the case of [3][3], we have 100 being added to 39, which is the element in [0][3].  This is the code that's causing the issue:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < P; j++)
        {

            // adds 100 to the previously-generated number in the original matrix
            if (i == j)
            {
                Matrix_M[i][j] = rand() % 100 + 100;
            }

            // outputs the 'adjusted' matrix
            cout << left << setw(4) << Matrix_M[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

I also thought about using the following 'brute force' method:

```
Matrix_M[0][0] = (rand() % 100) + 100;
Matrix_M[1][1] = (rand() % 100) + 200;
Matrix_M[2][2] = (rand() % 100) + 300;
Matrix_M[3][3] = (rand() % 100) + 400;
Matrix_M[4][4] = (rand() % 100) + 500;
Matrix_M[5][5] = (rand() % 100) + 600;
Matrix_M[6][6] = (rand() % 100) + 700;
Matrix_M[7][7] = (rand() % 100) + 800;
Matrix_M[8][8] = (rand() % 100) + 900;
Matrix_M[9][9] = (rand() % 100) + 1000;
Matrix_M[10][10] = (rand() % 100) + 1100;
Matrix_M[11][11] = (rand() % 100) + 1200;
```

But, this too is not yielding the expected results.  Can someone offer some guidance on how to properly address this problem?

Thanks very much in advance.
-Ryan

Comment: You want `Matrix_M[0][0] += 100;`, `rand()` is creating a new random value instead of modifying the one you already set.

Comment: @GuyGreer - I'm setting the seed.  So, would that even matter?

Comment: see [`rand()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) Quote: This number is generated by an algorithm that returns a sequence of apparently non-related numbers **each time it is called**.

Comment: Yes, resetting the seed (which BTW, is usually bad practice) makes the random numbers output in the same order as the last time they were set, but where you're putting those numbers is different in the two cases.

Comment: Also note that your loop method and brute force method do not produce the same result (even after switching for the `+=`)

Comment: As you can remark, after reset the seed, your diagonal has same value (`+100`) than the first row.

Comment: BTW, you may have a dedicated method to print matrix, and you `addError` may be simplified to `for (int i = 0; i < std::min(N, P); ++i) { Matrix_M[i][i] += i * 100; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that you re-run the random generator. Since you use the same seed again, the numbers are the same:

- First, you generate your number (79,59,41,...) and put it in your matrix.
- Then, you generate the same numbers and put them in the *diagonal of the matrix* after having added 100 to it.

If you want to accomplish your goal, you must not re-run the random generator but use the previous value of the matrix. Instead of

```
    if (i == j)
    {
        Matrix_M[i][j] = rand() % 100 + 100; //re-runs rand()
    }
```

You want to do:

```
    if (i == j)
    {
        Matrix_M[i][j] += 100;
    }
```

Comment: This does the trick.  Thank you.  Quick question:  is it possible to vary the amount that we add to each node of the diagonal.  For instance, can we add 100 to [0][0], 200 to [1][1], etc.?

Comment: Instead of adding 100 you would have to add i * 100

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I introduced:  Matrix_M[i][j] += (i+1)*10;  in order to increment by 10 along the diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

1. You do not need a nested loop for modifying the diagonal. Use the fact that both indices are the same, i.e. `Matrix_M[i][i]` is**always** a diagonal
2. When youupdate the element you are making it incorrectly. What you do is `Matrix_M[i][j] = rand() % 100 + 100;` which **generates** a new number when what you need is to **update** the existing one

Looks like you are trying to verify that the RNG works "correctly". But what you do is as follows:

first loop: you generate a new random number for EACH element
second loop: you **only** generate new numbers for updated elements. That is where you discrepancy is :)

You can change your second loop the following way to do what you need:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < P; j++)
    {

        int num = rand() % 100 + 100; // this will ensure the SAME random sequence

        if (i == j)
        {
            Matrix_M[i][j] = num;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that in the `addError()` function you only set matrix elements on the diagonal but when initializing the matrix you use `rand` for **every** element. Therefore you'll find after a call of `addError()` the elements of the first row + 100 in your diagonal. What you can do is to add an else-clause where you just call `rand`, i.e.

```
if(i == j) {
    Matrix_M[i][j] = rand() % 100 + 100;
}
else {
    rand();
}
```